# Python google spreadsheet update in the wrong column

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm trying to update my google spreadsheet with python. Unfortunately my code always updates one column/cell to the left.

My code:

```
headers = wks2.row_values(7)
colToUpdate = headers.index("12.11.")


#find the char
cellLookup = wks2.find('Gul')
# get the cell to be updated
cellToUpdate = wks2.cell(cellLookup.row, colToUpdate)

# update the cell's value
cellToUpdate.value = 3
# put it in the queue
cell_list.append(cellToUpdate)
# now, do it
wks2.update_cells(cell_list)
```

`print(cell_list)` outputs [<Cell R8C6 3>]
but it it should be / it want it to be R8C7.

Can I change that he starts to count at 1 or just add +1 or something similar?

I've added a image of my spreadsheet.

[image: google spreadsheet screenshot]

If you need more information, feel free to ask!

Comment: If the image in your question is the situation of your current issue, can I ask you about the result situation you expect? By the way, are you using gspread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem.  Looking at this code:

```
headers = wks2.row_values(7)
colToUpdate = headers.index("12.11.")

#find the char
cellLookup = wks2.find('Gul')
# get the cell to be updated
cellToUpdate = wks2.cell(cellLookup.row, colToUpdate)
```

The line:

```
wks2.row_values(7)
```

along with the picture of your spreadsheet suggests that rows and columns are addressed via 1-based indexes.  That is, the first row or column have an index of `1` rather than `0`.  But The operation:

```
colToUpdate = headers.index("12.11.")
```

is returning a 0-based index into the list of headers.  So this value has to be translated between 0-based and 1-based scales.  That's why you're off by 1 column.  So just do:

```
colToUpdate = headers.index("12.11.") + 1
```

and you'll be all set, and you now know why this is necesary.

Comment: Such a simple solution. Works!

Comment: "off by 1 errors" are notorious, of which this is one common variety

Comment: I'm going to change the answer slightly, just in terms of basic form.  I think doing the scale change upon calculating the index is cleaner.  Then `colToUpdate` is always in the right units.